# Trouble resetting /tmp value to push mercurial changes

Tags: python, mercurial, fedora

I have been using mercurial for about a year and haven't had any issues.

Today I ran into an issue for the first time.

When I try to push to the remote server with

```
$ hg push
```

I get the following response

```
searching for changes
remote: abort: No space left on device
abort: unexpected response: empty string
```

I googled this issue and found that it is a documented issue, and I found the following excerpt from [Mercurial FAQ](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/FAQ#FAQ.2FCommonProblems.I_get_a_.22no_space_left.22_or_.22disk_quota_exceeded.22_on_push):

> 4.28. I get a "no space left" or "disk quota exceeded" on push

I get a "no space left" or "disk quota exceeded" on push, but there is plenty of space or/and I have no quota limit on the device where the remote hg repository is.

The problem comes probably from the fact that mercurial uses /tmp (or one of the directory define by environment variables $TMPDIR, $TEMP or $TMP) to uncompress the bundle received on the wire. The decompression may then reach device limits.

You can of course set $TMPDIR to another location on remote in the default shell configuration file, but it will be potentially used by other processes than mercurial. Another solution is to set a hook in a global .hgrc on remote. See the description of how to set a hook for changing tmp directory on remote when pushing.

I have created the hook in my `/etc/mercurial/hgrc` file that looks like this

```
[hooks]
pre-serve.tmpdir = python:hgenviron.settmpdir
```

and then I am supposed to create `hgenviron.py`

```
import os
#see http://docs.python.org/lib/module-tempfile.html
def settmpdir(ui, repo, hooktype, node=None, source=None, **kwargs):
        os.environ["TMPDIR"] = "/home/tmp"
```

The problem I am having is that I don't know how to add this file to `$PYTHONPATH` in fedora

My operating system is Fedora 12 x86_64
I have python 2.6
I have mercurial 1.6.4

**UPDATE:**

I just added `hgenviron.py` to `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/hg/hgenviron.py` and

```
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/hg/hgenviron.py
export PYTHONPATH
```

to a `.sh` file in `/etc/profile.d`, along with the hook in `/etc/mercurial/`.

However I still get the error:

```
remote: abort: pre-serve.tmpdir hook is invalid (import of "hgenviron" failed) abort: 
no suitable response from remote hg!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is using the wrong import statement. It should be `from hg import hgenviron`

For setting PYTHONPATH Depends on how/where you want to add it.

In `/etc/profile.d` you can find a set of scripts that are ran when bash is loaded. `/etc/profile` is the global file, which calls the scripts and has this comment:

```
# System wide environment and startup programs, for login setup
# Functions and aliases go in /etc/bashrc

# It's NOT good idea to change this file unless you know what you
# are doing. Much better way is to create custom.sh shell script in
# /etc/profile.d/ to make custom changes to environment. This will
# prevent need for merging in future updates.
```

`/etc/profile` is ran when the bash environment is loaded. Locally to the user, you edit `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` (if they doesn't exist, you can create them). These scripts are ran when the specific user logs in. You should examine these files in detail to understand how the environment is created and setup.

You would add something like this:

```
PYTHONPATH=/home/tmp:$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.I will read up on it. I think what further has me confused is that currently when I run <code>$ echo $PYTHONPATH</code> it returns an empty string, but it seems that mercurial is working without it.

Comment: @ejs5 It should, python itself uses the site module to fill out sys.path, which the contents of PYTHONPATH is inserted into. This means that PYTHONPATH is just an easy way to add paths for python to find modules in.

Comment: I just added hgenviron.py to /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/hg/hgenviron.py and PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/hg/hgenviron.py
export PYTHONPATH
to a sh file in /etc/profile.d, along with the hook in /etc/mercurial/ however I still get the error: remote: abort: pre-serve.tmpdir hook is invalid (import of "hgenviron" failed)
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!

Comment: I added the last issue as an update to the original post so that it is easier to read.

Comment: @Ed Sullivan It's the directory containing the .py file or python modules not the file itself. But, you do not (or should not) have to do this at all.  The import statement should look like this, without setting PYTHONPATH, `from hg import hgenviron` Since /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ is already added to sys.path with the site module.

Comment: "The problem is using the wrong import statement. It should be from hg import hgenviron" which import statement? i see "import os" in hgenviron.py which is certainly fine. which import do you mean? thx for help

Comment: @thomas I mean he was using the wrong import statement for calling hgenviron into the hooks

Answer (score 1):

If you're struggling to get to the bottom of the PYTHONPATH issue, you can specifically state the location of the hgenviron.py file.

`pre-serve.tmpdir = python:/var/hg/hgenviron.py:settmpdir`

Note that settmpdir is then called with a `:` rather than `.` in the original example.